# Need help cleaning, and editing sound effects using multiple mics

Tags: pro-tools, effects, sound, sound-editing, cleaning

So my question is this; I'm trying to figure out a good way to edit, and clean my sfx recording with  3-4 mics. My main question what are your general steps ? Do you import everything into PT first sync all the tracks then move to RX. Or do you bring all the tracks into RX clean them up individually then sync up in PT?

I realize every situation is different and this is just a general example question but recently I've had my head wrapped around it.

Thanks
-Jeff

Comment: Thanks everyone, Your answers were exactly what I was looking for, to help solve my problem and improve my overall workflow/clear my head from my own confusion haha Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bring them all in and sync them first, then do a broad chop of all of the unusable stuff.  This is so that I can cover those tracks with crossfades, which I can't do in RX.  Once I have my basic edits completed I'll do an RX pass, then reimport to protools for mixdowns.

Comment: Thanks Rene, Going to defiantly try this when I get home!!

Comment: If you have RX4 the new connect audiosuite function makes this process a lot easier! You don't have to export and re-import anymore, just send your audio to RX4 and send it back into pro tools once you've cleaned up your audio. It's a pretty clean workflow.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to always import everything into PT, make your choice which 'blend' of mics suit each other over the edits.

Then audiosuite/RX anything needed, but keep the original in place, muted, or on an inactive track.

My personal experience is to go as easy on the denoiser as possible, and use volume and eq to fix up things.

Happy mixing :-)

Jason

Answer (score 1):

I bring everything into Pro Tools and clean with RX or EQ/Compression inside of ProTools.  It's makes it easier to keep a copy to go back to the original if needed as well as keep everything in sync and process your files more "in the mix" of how your finished tracks will sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure that it matters too much either way, so I'd probably go with your preference.

I'd personally sync them first because then I can swap between them to hear what other mics heard when refining the sound.  Soloing the tracks to work on them individually is always an option even if they are already in the project and synced.  I would certainly work on getting each channel cleaned up individually before I did any serious effort at blending them together though.